# SQL Comment in CodeIgniter Active Record?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter

I'm moving a project to CodeIgniter and want to take advantage of Active Record.  However, I haven't found a way to append a SQL comment to the queries.  In the existing code the query looks something like this:

```
UPDATE table
SET column = 'value'
WHERE  ID = passed value;
-- Transacted by ' .$_SESSION['Name']
```

I've search Google and SO and not found the answer to how to add that last "Transacted by" comment without coding the whole thing directly and using `$this->db->query('.....')`

Comment: What exactly are the advantages of Active Record? Why not code nice clear SQL queries using db->query()? SQL is an abstraction layer over a relational database engine. Active Record is a, uhhhm, abstraction layer over that abstraction layer? Then you can add all the comment you need and real database experts can actually read your queries and help you. And why would you want to insert comments into a Active Record query when you can comment the Active Record construction itself in PHP? Is the database going to do anything with those comments?

Comment: @PatrickSavalle, the comments are for the DBA who has an audit set up to pick these up.  I don't know why comments rather than insert into a table, but mine is not to reason why, mine is but to do and die().  :)  As for why Active Record, it does decrease the code necessary to implement.  Besides, I was told to do AR (see above pun).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kudos to Darrrrrren for getting me on the right track.

I defined a variable in my controller like this:
`$this->sqlStamp      = ' /*  Executed by ' .strtoupper( $this->router->class .'->' .$this->router->method) .' for ' .strtoupper( $this->session->userdata('displayName') ) .'*/ ';`

For Updates and deletes I was able to tack on 
`->where('1=1'.$this->sqlStamp, NULL, false)` .

I wasn't able to get a solution to Inserts since they have no where statement and attempts to inject the comments elsewhere didn't seem to work.  I ended up running this before the inserts to give the DBA something to look for:
`$this->db->get_where('Same_TableName','0=1'.$this->sqlStamp);`

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this is possible within ActiveRecord, as AR's functionality is a little restrictive.  One option that may work is using a custom string for your "where" clause, and sticking your transaction comment at the end of your custom "where" string.  I haven't tested this myself.

Even if you have to do the query manually, CI provides some nice escaping functions (`$this->db->escape` for numbers, `$this->db->escape_str` for 'where' strings and `$this->db->escape_like_str` for 'where like' strings) that should make your own queries safe - I know in most of my more complex CI apps I need to write custom queries for about 1/5 of my queries due to the restrictiveness of AR.